# Sending data to GCM Android application over .NET

Tags: android, asp.net, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Im sending data from my .NET application to GCM trough a POST.
1st my android device gets an Id, which it POST to my ASP.NET application.
then i have a simple button on my website "Send a message" , this posts data to GCM in a JSON format.

```
Private Function SendNotification(ByVal JSonData As String) As String
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(sender As       Object,         certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) True
    '/// Creating POST.
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send")
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "Content-Type: application/json"
    request.Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization: key={0}", MyAPIKey))

    '/// Converting data to byte array.
    Dim postData As String = JSonData
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    '/// Post
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    '/// Response
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return responseFromServer
End Function
```

JsonData byval contains :

```
{ "collapse_key":"DitIsEenUniekeIdentifier",
  "time_to_live":108,
  "delay_while_idle":true,
  "data": {
    "MessageId":1,
    "TestInformation":"BlieBloeBlaaaa tadaaa!"
   },
   "registration_ids":["APA91bFYQbSDzQDsoRrR3bnKtH_o72kQ7oiArg79WNz8qeCVoe6Kxu_BdcVftX1pGOfwLCLZbf_D3b7-V2yIaVasHxWXbn35nJO1bIiDzF84ifCHKJTyK3KiZmHZwAJliVIFcZFEVEsKTRiXWgpm9WWmnPrsbKvASy6FZyv4Eyfv-K526Q38Hjs"]
   }"
```

Which seems to be correct when i check google dev pages.
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

I was able before to send to GCM with the same function except i was using plain text then.
This is the first time trying the Json.
I changed the header of the post.
      request.ContentType = "Content-Type: application/json"
Which was before
      request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

The data i was sending in plain text :

```
Dim postData As String = String.Format("registration_id={0}&data.payload={1}&collapse_key={2}", ReceiverKey, Message, collaspeKey)
```

The error message im getting from GCM : MissingRegistration
According to google :

Registration ID

Check that the request contains a registration ID (either in the registration_id parameter in a plain text message, or in the registration_ids field in JSON). 
Happens when error code is MissingRegistration.

Anny help is greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong :

`request.ContentType = "Content-Type: application/json"`

Change it to :

`request.ContentType = "application/json"`

**A short explanation :**

Since the content type you sent was invalid, Google used the default content type, which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`. And expecting this content type, they didn't find the registration ID, which resulted in `MissingRegistration`.